# android how to get user about me info from facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I want to fetch info for "user_about_me " permission in facebook app.

I able to get for email, location, but i try to fetch for about_me its giving only id. I want all info. How can i do that?

I did like this,

```
bundle.putString("fields", "about");
String about_me=facebook.request("me", bundle);
```

Its giving only id.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String about_me = Facebook.request("me");

This will do, you don't need to add a bundle as a second parameter, afaik.

Comment: Ok. Its giving all info, How can i get one by one?

Comment: it might be giving you the json data as string, convert the returned string to JSONObject and then extract values. you might want to see the the following link to extract data from jsonobject.

Comment: one thing, i want to get all user info from facebook and want to send to different server. My question is every time i have fetch data through json or there is any other way?

Comment: send the returned string to server?, and process it on server side?, if you need values, you can check if Facebook returns user data in other format than json.

Comment: Actualy from my app if anyone open facebook and loged in then i want all the info about that user like first name , last name should go to the server and one web acount will sign up from that info . How can i do that? Any idea?

Comment: i will post some code in the next answer, let me know if that helps , so that i can delete this answer.

Comment: I know this. What i ask is there any direct way to send all data to server. Bcz it may contain huge data, every time retrieving and send take too much memory.

Comment: no, either u send the complete string or get required data and send it.