# getting basic information from facebook access token in android

Tags: android, facebook

How to get the basic information like first name, last name, user id from facebook access token in android. I am able to login and get the access token but next problem is to get the basic information of the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131666/get-user-basic-information-using-facebook-login-button-plugin

Comment: [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345535/android-how-to-get-user-about-me-info-from-facebook/7345618#7345618)

Comment: @ekjyot have you checked my post??

Answer (score 4):

Check this Code for Getting User Information ;

```
Bundle params1 = new Bundle();
params1.putString("fields","picture");
Log.v("sss", authenticatedFacebook.request("me"));
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("me"));
String id=jObject.getString("id");
String name=jObject.getString("name");
String email=jObject.getString("email");
try {
   URL img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {}
try {
  Bitmap mIcon1 =     BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Code for getting id , name , email of Logged user in Facebook and also image of the logged user.

If you need further help in Facebook check this links

[Graph Api in Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

[Facebook Birthday Details of friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350567/facebook-friends-birthdays-in-android/5350705#5350705)

Ensure you added required Permission in this [Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: Nice Answer :) and i have one more doubt